# powershell: delete files previously used as argument inside script

Tags: windows, powershell, fonts

I need to periodically scan a folder for new fontfiles to install and delete them afterwards using a powershell script.

During processing I want to skip already installed files and to achieve that I need to resolve the "real" fontname of the provided file.
I figured out everything and it seems to work everything but the file deletion.

The deletion did work until I added the font name resolution using this GlythTypeInterface Object. It seems like the invoked object does "file lock" the fontfile resulting in an UnauthorizedAccessException.

Thats why I tried some garbage collection stuff I found but I can't make it work.

My code so far:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore
$FONTS = 0x14
$Path="C:\_fonts_to_install"
$FontItem = Get-Item -Path $Path
$FontList = Get-ChildItem -Path "$FontItem\*" -Include ('*.fon','*.otf','*.ttc','*.ttf')
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$objFolder = $objShell.Namespace($FONTS)
$Fontdir = dir $Path
$username = $env:UserName

foreach($File in $FontList) {
        $try = $true
        $installedFonts = @(Get-ChildItem C:\Users\$username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | Select-Object basename)
        $fontObject = New-Object -TypeName Windows.Media.GlyphTypeface -ArgumentList $File.fullname
        $fontName = $fontObject.Win32FamilyNames.Values
        Write-Host $fontName
        $fontObject = $null
        Remove-Variable fontObject
        foreach($font in $installedFonts)
        {
            if ($font -match $fontName)
            {
                $try = $false
            }
        }
        if ($try)
        {
            $objFolder.CopyHere($File.fullname)
        }
        Write-Host $File
        Remove-Item $File -Force -Verbose
}
```

Comment: I can rename and delete a font without removing the `$fontObject` or the `$fontName`. Sure you have the rights to remove them without creating the `$fontObject`?

Comment: yes I am sure. Removing works fine if I remove the "Windows.Media.GlyphTypeface" font name resolution.